# Is it possible order one AdvancedDataGrid column by another column?

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, sorting

I have an ArrayCollection with Name, Date, Quantity.

My DataGrid shows Name and Quantity only.

Is possible, when I click on Name Header, to order the DataGrid by Date?
(and not by Name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using
**ObjectUtil.dateCompare(dateA, dateB);**
with **sortCompareFunction** in your DataGridColumn

Check out the below example:

```
       private function date_sortCompareFunc(itemA:Object, itemB:Object):int {
            var dateA:Date = new Date(Date.parse(itemA.dob));
            var dateB:Date = new Date(Date.parse(itemB.dob));
            return ObjectUtil.dateCompare(dateA, dateB);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [sortCompareFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#sortCompareFunction) on the column you want to sort.

Comment: can you make a short example?

i have try this:

`
private function myCompare(a:Object, b:Object, fields:Array = null):int
{
    if(String(a).toLowerCase() == 'all')
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if(String(b).toLowerCase() == 'all')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    
    var s:Sort = new Sort();
    var f:Function = s.compareFunction;
    return f.call(null,a,b,fields);
}
`

but I don't know where put the second field name.
example:

Column field is "NAME", and I want to order by the field (not in grid) named "ORDER"

Comment: I can't really make a short sample based on the lack of code you have provided us.  Can you provide a short, runnable, self contained sample?

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Rudra! starting by your function I have made this:

```
private function MysortCompareFunc(itemA:Object, itemB:Object):int {

// I order the column FIELD1 by the column FIELD2

var ValueA:String = String(itemA.FIELD2);
var ValueB:String = String(itemB.FIELD2);

return ObjectUtil.stringCompare(ValueA, ValueB); // or another Compare

}
```

// and in the column of FIELD1 of DataGrid I put:

```
sortCompareFunction="MysortCompareFunc"
```

THANK YOU!